# Does overclocking the usb polling rate for a mouse have any side effects?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, mouse

I have a `125mhz` simple Microsoft mouse and have been using it overclocked at `500mhz`. However I seem to face a little mouse lag.

Is this possible? Can overclocking mice cause lag problems?

Comment: You've tagged with with CS:GO, but I don't see anything in the question that's specific to that game.

Comment: I thought it is maybe particular to cs:go.

Comment: Does the mouse lag happen only in CS:GO?  Or does it happen everywhere?

Comment: @fbueckert if it wasnt so why would I tag cs:go?

Comment: You still haven't clarified, though.  Does this mouse lag happen only in CS:GO?  Or does it happen elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I researched a bit into this, overclocking your mouse/usb port should not have any side effects on your system or mouse, this including any glitch or damage. But only if you did your over clocking correctly.

At 125mhz the delay is 8ms and at 500 the delay should be at 4ms.

But every mouse has its built in speed limit, overclocking it too 500 doesn't mean that it will achieve 500 for sure.

So the bottom line is, no, overclocking should not create mouse lag problems if you did it correctly.